# Python interval interesction

Tags: python, algorithm, intervals

My problem is as follows:

having file with list of intervals:

```
1 5
2 8
9 12
20 30
```

And a range of

```
0 200
```

I would like to do such an intersection that will report the positions [start end] between my intervals inside the given range.

For example:

```
8 9
12 20
30 200
```

Beside any ideas how to bite this, would be also nice to read some thoughts on optimization, since as always the input files are going to be huge.

Comment: Are intervals sorted?

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you are asking, but considering that there is only 1 range you are matching against, then O(n) is the worst case if you need to scan the entire file. If you can keep it in memory and need to do multiple queries, then sorting them by start and end in different binary trees for example could help...

Comment: don't you have 0 1 as well ?

Comment: It is feasible to load full file into memory. To visualize more what I mean. If you take a piece of paper and on it you draw a line from 0 to 200. And now add to this line intervals: ex. 1-5, 2-8, 20-30. Now What I want is to have the start-end positions inside our 0-200 interval where there are no added small intervals, places where they do not map. Does that help?

Comment: @njzk2 this is all just an trivial example. But in real set there is almost 0 possibility, that something will start from the 0 position, but still it can be so

Comment: Yes. Are the intervals in input file sorted? In other words is it possible to have 10-20 1-5 in *that* order, or is it always 1-5 10-20?

Comment: Now they are just throw randomly in file, but they can be sorted simply with bash, so yes, let's say they are sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this solution works as long the intervals are ordered by the start point and does not require to create a list as big as the total range.

## code

```
with open("0.txt") as f:
    t=[x.rstrip("\n").split("\t") for x in f.readlines()]
    intervals=[(int(x[0]),int(x[1])) for x in t]

def find_ints(intervals, mn, mx):
    next_start = mn
    for x in intervals:
        if next_start < x[0]:
            yield next_start,x[0]
            next_start = x[1]
        elif next_start < x[1]:
            next_start = x[1]
    if next_start < mx:
        yield next_start, mx

print list(find_ints(intervals, 0, 200))
```

## output:

(in the case of the example you gave)

```
[(0, 1), (8, 9), (12, 20), (30, 200)]
```

Comment: there is a problem: The highest interval in output ends on : 9980032
The range instead of 200 is now set for 249250622. Do you know what is happening, or do you need more information? The data I passed is formatted as requested (increasing order of the start position)

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem. You should get the last interval as 9980032, 249250622. At least is what it's doing if you add an interval in the one you gave as example (e.g. (5, 9980032)) and you use 249250622 as mx

Comment: I don't know, I've put the file in here if you want to check:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftavov170n8987j/0
The max range used: 249250622

Comment: I think I found the problem, when you read the file you don't convert the string in int, so the comparison will be done  lexicographically instead than numerically, I added the code for reading the file.

Answer (score 1):

Rough algorithm:

1. create an array of booleans, all set to false `seen = [False]*200`
2. Iterate over the input file, for each line `start end` set `seen[start]` .. `seen[end]` to be `True`
3. Once done, then you can trivially walk the array to find the unused intervals.

In terms of optimisations, if the list of input ranges is sorted on start number, then you can track the highest seen number and use that to filter ranges as they are processed -
e.g. something like

```
for (start,end) in input:
  if end<=lowest_unseen:
    next
  if start<lowest_unseen:
    start=lowest_unseen
  ...
```

which (ignoring the cost of the original sort) should make the whole thing O(n) - you go through the array once to tag seen/unseen and once to output unseens.

Seems I'm feeling nice. Here is the (unoptimised) code, assuming your input file is called `input`

```
seen = [False]*200
file = open('input','r')
rows = file.readlines()
for row in rows:
  (start,end) = row.split(' ')
  print "%s %s" % (start,end)
  for x in range( int(start)-1, int(end)-1 ):
    seen[x] = True

print seen[0:10]

in_unseen_block=False
start=1
for x in range(1,200):
  val=seen[x-1]
  if val and not in_unseen_block:
    continue
  if not val and in_unseen_block:
    continue
  # Must be at a change point.
  if val:
    # we have reached the end of the block
    print "%s %s" % (start,x)
    in_unseen_block = False
  else:
    # start of new block
    start = x
    in_unseen_block = True
# Handle end block
if in_unseen_block:
  print "%s %s" % (start, 200)
```

I'm leaving the optimizations as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: sorry, since I'm still a pyton newbie, I do have some problems in implementing your tips

Comment: Cool, thanks. Howebver with 249250621 as my range, memory error. Guess loading all in memory wasn't such a good idea

Answer (score 1):

If you make a note every time that one of your input intervals either opens or closes, you can do what you want by putting together the keys of `opens` and `closes`, sort into an ordered set, and you'll be able to essentially think, "okay, let's say that each adjacent pair of numbers forms an interval. Then I can focus all of my logic on these intervals as discrete chunks."

```
myRange = range(201)
intervals = [(1,5), (2,8), (9,12), (20,30)]
opens = {}
closes = {}

def open(index):
    if index not in opens:
        opens[index] = 0
    opens[index] += 1

def close(index):
    if index not in closes:
        closes[index] = 0
    closes[index] += 1

for start, end in intervals:
    if end > start: # Making sure to exclude empty intervals, which can be problematic later
        open(start)
        close(end)

# Sort all the interval-endpoints that we really need to look at
oset = {0:None, 200:None}
for k in opens.keys():
    oset[k] = None
for k in closes.keys():
    oset[k] = None
relevant_indices = sorted(oset.keys())

# Find the clear ranges
state = 0
results = []
for i in range(len(relevant_indices) - 1):
    start = relevant_indices[i]
    end = relevant_indices[i+1]

    start_state = state
    if start in opens:
        start_state += opens[start]
    if start in closes:
        start_state -= closes[start]

    end_state = start_state
    if end in opens:
        end_state += opens[end]
    if end in closes:
        end_state -= closes[end]
    state = end_state

    if start_state == 0:
        result_start = start
        result_end = end
        results.append((result_start, result_end))

for start, end in results:
    print(str(start) + " " + str(end))
```

This outputs:

```
0 1
8 9
12 20
30 200
```

The intervals don't need to be sorted.

Comment: Works nicely, however when 249250621 passed as range, memory Error. Like I said, the files are huge

Comment: I will divide the file and range into few parts, that should do the trick.

Comment: Irek, I made some modifications that I think will solve your problem of running out of memory. See if it does it for you.

Comment: That's great, works very quickly. At the first look seems to be working as expected. Thanks, for the ready solution

Comment: I noticed first inconsistencies. Sometimes it gives the correct start point, but the end point is like 2x fold higher value

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be a duplicate of [Merging intervals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43363350/merging-intervals-in-python/49718028#49718028).

If I understood well the problem, you have a list of intervals (1 5; 2 8; 9 12; 20 30) and a range (0 200), and you want to get the positions outside your intervals, but inside given range. Right?

There's a Python library that can help you on that: [python-intervals](https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/python-intervals) (also available from PyPI using pip). Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of that library.

Assuming you import this library as follows:

```
import intervals as I
```

It's quite easy to get your answer. Basically, you first want to create a disjunction of intervals based on the ones you provide:

```
inters = I.closed(1, 5) | I.closed(2, 8) | I.closed(9, 12) | I.closed(20, 30)
```

Then you compute the complement of these intervals, to get everything that is "outside":

```
compl = ~inters
```

Then you create the union with [0, 200], as you want to restrict the points to that interval:

```
print(compl & I.closed(0, 200))
```

This results in:

```
[0,1) | (8,9) | (12,20) | (30,200]
```