# Merging intervals in Python

Tags: python

I am very new to Python programming and have come across a problem statement i have no clue how to solve.
I have four lines of input:

```
0 1
2 4
6 7
3 5
```

For accepting these 4 lines of input i can do the below:

```
for i in range(4):
    a,b = list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
```

I am supposed to merge the intervals into(Output) :

```
0 1
2 5
6 7
```

Intervals (2,4) and (3,5) they should be merged into one (2,5).

I am not sure how should i go about this ?

Can someone help me in getting a direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're expecting as output doesn't seem to have a specific pattern to follow. You would do well by clarifying if there is any `(2, 4), (3, 5) = (2, 5)` could mean the min and max of the two sets.

Comment: Yes thanks Parousia , i think that is what this means but there has to be an overlap between two sets.

Comment: I came up with this `(a, b )= min(min((2,4),(3, 5))), max(max((2,4),(3,5)))`. But there needs to be a more defined pattern. Perhaps more data would help in deciphering such a pattern

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a standard problem, here is a question asked in java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670849/merge-overlapping-intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from functools import reduce
# inp = [(0,1),(2,9),(6,7),(3,5)]
inp = [(0,1),(2,4),(6,7),(3,5)]
print(inp)
def merge(li,item):
    if li:
        if li[-1][1] >= item[0]:
            li[-1] = li[-1][0], max(li[-1][1],item[1])
            return li
    li.append(item)
    return li
print(reduce(merge, sorted(inp), []))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a Python library that handles intervals arithmetic, consider [python-interval](https://pypi.org/project/python-intervals/). Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of that library.

```
import intervals as I

interval = I.empty()
for i, j in [(0, 1), (2, 4), (6, 7), (3, 5)]:
    interval = interval | I.closed(i, j)
print(interval)
```

results in

```
[0,1] | [2,5] | [6,7]
```

See its [documentation](https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/python-intervals) for more information.