# How to collapse overlapping intervals [start-end] and keep the smaller?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe of intervals defined by 2 numerical coordinates, 'start' and 'end'.

I am trying to collapse all intervals that are overlapping, and keep the inner coordinates.

```
index start end  
0 10 40  
1 13 34  
2 50 100  
3 44 94
```

Output: The same Pandas dataframe with collapsed intervals and inner coordinates. Two intervals overlap if they share a common point, including closed endpoints. Intervals that only have an open endpoint in common do not overlap.

e.g. The intervals with row index = [0,1] are overlapping. I want to collapse these 2 intervals into a new interval, which has new_start == max([10, 13]) and new_end == min([40,34]). The collapse interval for row index [0,1] will have new_start = 13, new_end = 34.

```
index start end  
0 13 34  
1 50 94
```

The size of the dataframe is 2M rows, therefore I am also looking for an efficient way to do it.

Comment: Its not quite clear what do to when you find a row that overlaps with one of the previous rows. Do you keep the first occurance? Do you remove a row only if its fully contained by another row, or does any overlap cause it to be removed? Why did the `10 40` row dissapper and how did `50 94` row appear?

Comment: Are the overlapping intervals consecutive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging intervals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43363350/merging-intervals-in-python)

Comment: @Chris There is a big difference between processing of python list and a huge dataframe with a several million of samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it can be done like below

```py
df.groupby(((df.shift()["end"] - df["start"])<0).cumsum()).agg({"start":"min", "end":"max"})
```

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, the result is not equal to the result expected by the author.